# how to open data in browser PDF format?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

i get data (price of volvo cars) my xml or sql database, i have "xyz.aspx" page. How can i open pdf in a web browser. But i want to learn how can i open pdf(data from sql datatable ) xyz.aspx or data in another.aspx...

Sample: [Volvos'prices pdf](http://www.volvocars.com/tr/tools/Pages/fiyat%20listesi.aspx)

Comment: The PDF opened fine in my browser.  Adobe in Chrome.

Answer (score 5):

Let's say that you have a table like that :

```
CREATE TABLE PDFTable (
    [PDFID] [bigint] IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL ,
    [PDFFile] [varbinary(max)]
)
```

and you store your PDF files in this table in binary format. And you want to expose your PDF files to your visitors like that :

> http://www.mysite.com/getpdf.aspx?pdfid=12

Here is a sample for reading binary pdf data from database and writing it to response stream :

```
// PageLoad event of your getpdf.aspx page :
long pdfId= Convert.ToInt64(Request.QueryString["pdfid"]);

using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(
        "SELECT PDFFile FROM PDFTable WHERE PDFId = @PDFID", conn))
    {
        command.Parameters.Add("@PDFID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = pdfId;
        conn.Open();

        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.BinaryWrite((byte[]) command.ExecuteScalar());
    }
}
```

This page will result your client to open pdf in his/her browser.

Answer (score 0):

There are two steps to this.

1. Produce a pdf containing the data.
2. Deliver the pdf to the browser

For step 1: There are many libraries available for pdf writing. Just pick one. Doing your own PDF generation is probably not viable, as the format is very complicated.

For step 2: Set the Content.Headers to included a mime/pdf contentType, and use BinaryWrite to putout the pdf data to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Also you need to set your mime type to "application/pdf" by setting the content-type header.